Google verifyIDToken failed to log in
I use google-auth-library, when I accept a login token from the frontend, verifies it is legit, but it gets an error, this is the log
Failed to log in: FetchError: Failed to retrieve verification certificates: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 142.251.43.10:443is.com/oauth2/v1/certs failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT

it is the code
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");
const User = require("./models/user");
const socketManager = require("./server-socket");

//Create a new OAuth client used to verify Google sign-in
const CLIENT_ID = "395785444978-7b9v7l0ap2h3308528vu1ddnt3rqftjc.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);

// accepts a login token from the frontend, and verifies that it's legit
function verify(token) {
  return client
    .verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,
    })
    .then((ticket) => ticket.getPayload());
}

I tried to update the google-auth-library, but it doesn't work
I can use the browser to enter the URL (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs)
I don't know why that

You can see the google official example in here
  // Verify the id_token, and access the claims.
  const ticket = await oAuth2Client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: oAuth2Client.credentials.id_token,
    audience: keys.web.client_id,
  });

Demo
The code performs OAuth 2.0 authentication with Google, verifies the ID token, and displays the verification result in the browser. It involves setting up an OAuth2 client, generating an authorization URL, handling the OAuth2 callback, and displaying the result.
I modify a little bits from official example
#1 const open = require('open');
it requires ES module, so I replaced with child_process for launching Browser.
const { exec } = require('child_process');

#2 Display ID token verification result in Browser
#3 Callback URL as same as my configuration
From
          if (req.url.indexOf('/oauth2callback') > -1) {

To
          if (req.url.indexOf('/callback') > -1) {

URL
https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager

OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

demo.js
'use strict';

const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const destroyer = require('server-destroy');
const keys = require('./oauth2.keys.json');

/**
 * Start by acquiring a pre-authenticated oAuth2 client.
 */
async function main() {
  const oAuth2Client = await getAuthenticatedClient();

  // Verify the id_token, and access the claims.
  const ticket = await oAuth2Client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: oAuth2Client.credentials.id_token,
    audience: keys.web.client_id,
  });

  // Display the ticket in the browser
  displayTicketInBrowser(ticket);

  // You can use this info to get user information too.
  const url = 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names';
  const res = await oAuth2Client.request({ url });
  console.log(res.data);
}

/**
 * Display the ticket in the browser.
 */
function displayTicketInBrowser(ticket) {
  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('<html><body><h1>ID Token Verification Result</h1>');
    res.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ticket, null, 2) + '</pre>');
    res.write('</body></html>');
    res.end();
    server.destroy();
  }).listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3001');
    openBrowser('http://localhost:3001');
  });
  destroyer(server);
}

/**
 * Open the browser with the given URL.
 */
function openBrowser(url) {
  const start = (process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'open' :
                 process.platform === 'win32' ? 'start ""' :
                 'xdg-open');
  console.log(`Opening browser with command: ${start} "${url}"`);
  exec(`${start} "${url}"`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Failed to open browser:', err);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Create a new OAuth2Client, and go through the OAuth2 content
 * workflow. Return the full client to the callback.
 */
function getAuthenticatedClient() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // create an oAuth client to authorize the API call. Secrets are kept in a `keys.json` file,
    // which should be downloaded from the Google Developers Console.
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
      keys.web.client_id,
      keys.web.client_secret,
      keys.web.redirect_uris[0]
    );

    // Generate the url that will be used for the consent dialog.
    const authorizeUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    });

    // Open an http server to accept the oauth callback. In this simple example, the
    // only request to our webserver is to /oauth2callback?code=<code>
    const server = http
      .createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
          if (req.url.indexOf('/callback') > -1) {
            // acquire the code from the querystring, and close the web server.
            const qs = new url.URL(req.url, 'http://localhost:3000').searchParams;
            const code = qs.get('code');
            console.log(`Code is ${code}`);
            res.end('Authentication successful! Please return to the console.');
            server.destroy();

            // Now that we have the code, use that to acquire tokens.
            const r = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
            // Make sure to set the credentials on the OAuth2 client.
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(r.tokens);
            console.info('Tokens acquired.');
            resolve(oAuth2Client);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      })
      .listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
        // open the browser to the authorize url to start the workflow
        openBrowser(authorizeUrl);
      });
    destroyer(server);
  });
}

main().catch(console.error);

Install Dependencies
package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "google-auth-library": "^9.10.0",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "open": "^10.1.0",
    "server-destroy": "^1.0.1",
    "url": "^0.11.3"
  }
}

npm install

Download my credential file
Save as oauth2.keys.json

File tree

Run it
Browser will be open automatically.
node demo.js

Result

